# How to fix blank error in MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a simple login stored procedure in MySQL for simple testing purposes. I am stumped as to why it errors out. Here is my code:

```
create procedure prLogin (IN userID varchar(20), IN pw varchar(20))

begin

select * from userlogin 
inner join users on userlogin.id = users.userid 
where userlogin.username = userID and userlogin.password = pw;

end
```

As I mentioned above, this code fails, but offers no clue as to why.

Comment: and what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can find is that you have not change your delimiter, If you don't change it, the whole statement will break at the last `;` which happens on line `a.password = pw;`.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE prLogin (IN userID varchar(20), IN pw varchar(20))
BEGIN
    SELECT  a.*, b.*
    FROM    userlogin a
            INNER JOIN users b
                ON a.id = b.userid 
    WHERE   a.username = userID AND 
            a.password = pw;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

by changing the character of delimiter (*anything you want and my chosen chars are `$$`*), the statement will stop on the new character and not on `;`.

Comment: So, now I've tried a very basic stored proc in an attempt to eliminate errors one at at time. The following doesn't work either and I'm wondering about other possible causes:

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE prTester

BEGIN

SELECT * FROM users

END

DELIMITER ;

Comment: your procedure is still wrong. it should be `DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE prTester ()
BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM users ;
END $$
DELIMITER ;`

Comment: This still fails. The only hint given is that the error is DELIMITER ;

Comment: actually all the given code above are tested on my server and they are all working fine `:)`